# Custom site template exception on TaxonomyHiddenList feature activation on SharePoint 2013

Tags: site-template

I have created a site collection on Central Administration using the STS#0 template. Afterwards I deleted the newsfeed webpart and saved the site as template on Site Settings and saved the wsp to my hard drive.

Next I uploaded the wsp to a site collection where I have a webpart that creates a new site collection and applies a specific template after it is created. The webpart code is based on Waldek Mastykarz article "[Programmatically creating Sites and Site Collections from a Custom Web Template](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-sites-site-collections-custom-web-template/)".

All the code is executed without problems and the template is applied. Here's when the web template ListInstances results an exception. The message sequence of the ULS is as follow:

> 1. Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002
>
>    1. 0x80070002
>    2. 0x80070002    SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName=
>         ,bstrUrl=http://teamrooms.dev/teamrooms/NoNewsFeed/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList
>         ,METADATAFLAGS=59
>    3. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 0x80070002,
>         StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetList(String strUrl)
>         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.TryGetListByUrl(String url)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldElement.PerformFixUpIfLookUpField(Guid
>         fieldId, XmlNode xmlNodeOfAField, SPWeb web)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldElement.ElementActivated(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>         props, SPSqlCommand sqlcmdAppendOnly, SPWebApplication webApp, SPSite
>         site, SPWeb webNull, Boolean fForce)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionFieldsAndContentTypes(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>         props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags,
>         Boolean fForce)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>         props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web,
>         SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb
>         webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags
>         activateFlags, Boolean fForce)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition
>         featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties,
>         SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean
>         fMarkOnly)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid
>         featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version
>         version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties,
>         SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean
>         fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedCore(SPSite
>         site, SPWeb web, String sFeatures, Boolean fMarkOnly)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.<>c_*DisplayClass7.b*_6()
>         at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken userToken,
>         Boolean bResetContext, WaitCallback code, Object param)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedAtWeb(Byte[]&
>         userToken, Guid& tranLockerId, Int32 nZone, Guid databaseid, Guid
>         siteid, Guid webid, String sFeatures)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String
>         bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32
>         fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32
>         fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate,
>         Int32& plWebTemplateId)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String
>         bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32
>         fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32
>         fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate,
>         Int32& plWebTemplateId)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String
>         bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32
>         fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32
>         fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate,
>         Int32& plWebTemplateId)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate
>         webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate
>         featureWebTemplate)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate)
>         at  NewTeamRoom.<>c_*DisplayClass3.b*_0()
>         at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_3()
>         at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>         secureCode)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>         secureCode, Object param)     at
>         Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>         secureCode)     at  NewTeamRoom.ProvisionSiteCollection()     at 
>         NewTeamRoom.btnCreate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at
>         System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>         eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>         includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>         includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>         at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at
>         System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at
>         System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>         at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>         Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at
>         System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>         error)     at
>         System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>         context, AsyncCallback cb)     at
>         System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>         wr, HttpContext context)     at
>         System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>         rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>         Int32 flags)     at
>         System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>         rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>         Int32 flags)     at
>         System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>         pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at
>         System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>         pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at
>         System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>         rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>         Int32 flags)     at
>         System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>         rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>         Int32 flags)

If I try to create a new site using this template through UI or even if I create a site collection through the webpart using a saved template based on STS#0 without making any changes, everything works fine: no exceptions and the site collection is created.

I cannot understand why this is happening and I already lost quite sometime with this issue. Do someone have a clue how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tlooks like one of the last methods called is the PerformFixUpIfLookUpField. This method is used to rewrite the attribute values of List and WebID of lookupfields. It rewrites the url of the target list to the list guid and the url-token of the WebID to the guid of the target web. Is it possible that in the definition of the lookupfields an old guid is present?

I recently also had a problem with lookupfields and examined this method. You can find some of my findings in my blog post: http://martensboarterstun.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/how-to-create-a-list-definition-with-a-lookup-field-declaratively/

Maybe you can solve your problem with this information